# Expressjs - Angular loading not loading index page

Tags: angularjs, express, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm having issue developing an application using expressjs and angular. I'm loading angular, bootstrap etc from my index page. to test, I put a button  `<a ui-sref=about>about</a>` to go to `about` page. when I click the button from my `index` page, no problem. the page loads along with the libraries used in `index.html` and it console logs a message from `AboutController`. However, when I refresh the page `http://localhost:3000/about`, the page loads without loading the angular, bootstrap etc libraries. I know my `<script>` tags that load the those files are in `index.html` but I wonder if there is a way refresh the page from `http://localhost:3000/about` and load `index` first, then it would go to `about` or if my app could load the files in index on refresh making available the same files to `about` .

here is my file structure
[image: file structure]

Here is my code:

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
<li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
 <ui-view></ui-view>

</body>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/anim-in-out.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controllers/HomeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controllers/AboutController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Server.js

```js
/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/14/17.
 */
/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/14/17.
 */
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function (req,res,next) {

    res.sendFile('index.html');

})


app.get('/about', function (req,res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/partials/about.html');

})

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server running in PORT " + PORT);
});
```

main.js

```js
/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/5/17.
 */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);


console.log("in myApp");

myApp.config( function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('home',{
            url:'/home',
            templateUrl:'/partials/home.html',
            controller:'HomeController'


        })
        .state('about',{
            url:'/about',
            templateUrl:'/partials/about.html',
            controller:'AboutController'


        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('/#!/');
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

// /test.html#!/about
```

AboutController.js

```js
/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/14/17.
 */
/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/5/17.
 */
myApp.controller('AboutController',['$scope','$rootScope', '$rootScope', '$scope',
    function($rootScope, $scope) {


        console.log("Hello from about controller");

        $scope.hello = 'about';

    }]);/**
 * Created by carlosgonzalez on 4/14/17.
 */
```

about.html

```html
<div>{{hello}}</div>
```

Comment: Please do not tag AngularJS qestions wth `angular`. Use the `angularjs` tag instead. `angular` is for Angular version 2 and up. Thank you.

Comment: sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your server.js to make it renders the index.html.

```
app.get('/about', function (req,res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
})
```

Once index.html is rendered ui-router will trigger the in-browser routing and display your about page correctly.

Comment: If your app is a complete SPA, you can use `app.get('*', function (req,res) {})` to send `index.html` on all get requests

Comment: Thank you so much this worked for me ! Always the simplest things.